# Парсер для Avito

Tags: python, парсер

Пишу парсер для авито на Python в PyCharm. Возник вопрос. Можно ли сделать парсер для всех категорий? То есть универсальный? Я пишу парсер для авито, но для этого нужно выбирать категорию и тогда брать ссылку. Хочу спросить. Для этого нужно выбирать категорию и тогда копировать ссылку. Но ведь для разных категорий наверное и парсер не будет работать. Мне нужно парсить телефон, имя и название товара. Могу ли я просто в самом коде просто менять ссылку на страничку, которую нужно парсить? (эти ссылки будут отличаться, ведь категории разные), сработает ли так?

Извиняюсь, так часто "парсер" в одном письме давно не писал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Категорий ни так много, можешь указать ссылки в коде.

А по товару - Смотри ссылку , например `www.avito.ru/nizhniy_novgorod/avtomobili/audi_q7_2006_1916192398`

`_1916192398` - это номер лота и только он важен для перехода. Сайт делает редирект в нужную категорию и город сам.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Могу ли я выбрать категорию, скопировать ссылку в адресной строке, вставить в свой код, и затем мне в таблице (куда я хочу выложить полученные данные) будут те данные, которые я соответственно хочу. Подойдет ли один парсер (имя продавца, цена, название товара) на все категории? Просто буду копировать ссылку (она разная, в зависимости от категорий) и вставлять в свой код. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: так попробуй) скорей всего подойдет

Comment: понял, большое спасибо!